# Store the resulting list of a SELECT in a variable to count AND use the result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, update, count

I have stored procedure that uses a cursor and for every fetch a duplicate `SELECT`, once to determine the number of IDs found (`SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TableA WHERE something.. @cur_var`) and if the `COUNT(ID)` is bigger then a specified value, an `UPDATE` is issued for another Table `WHERE` the above IDs are used (`SELECT ID FROM TableA WHERE something.. @cur_var`)..

The idea is to have the `SELECT` stored in a variable (pseudo-code *idlist* = `SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TableA WHERE something.. @cur_var`). Then the length of this *list* is used in the `IF` (pseudo-code `IF`*length(idlist)*`>100`.
In this case the list is used again in the `WHERE` statement (pseudo-code again, `UPDATE TableB SET value = @cur_var WHERE ID IN idlist`)

I hope to be specific enough, I'd like to save the result of a `SELECT` in a variable. Then use the result in `WHERE IN variable` and the number of rows in the variable to use in an `IF`.

Working on Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition v9.00.3042.00, i.e. SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2

**EDIT**

I've tried to keep the procedure as reasonable as possible without giving away any private information..

My intention is to remove the duplicate code. The `SELECT` used in the `IF` and the `SELECT` used in the `WHERE` from the `UPDATE` are the same, except that I first need the `COUNT(ID)` and then the actual `ID`s

```
DECLARE @cur_id int; 
SET @cur_id = 0;

DECLARE Cur CURSOR FOR
    --this is actually a more complex SELECT but basically gives a list of IDs
    SELECT ID FROM TableC ORDER BY ID DESC

    OPEN Cur;
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @cur_id;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    --here I check if the count of found IDs (with value=NULL and IN the SELECT) is bigger than 5
    IF
    (
        SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TableA WHERE value=NULL AND ID IN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT(ID) FROM TableB WHERE ID = @cur_id
        )
    ) > 5
    BEGIN
        --if its bigger, set the value for every ID that is part of the ID list (the same select, but above the count, below no count) 
        UPDATE TableB
        SET value = @cur_id
        WHERE ID IN
        (
            SELECT ID FROM TableA WHERE value=NULL AND ID IN
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT(ID) FROM TableB WHERE ID = @cur_id
            )
        )
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @cur_id;
END
```

**EDIT 2:**

This is the closest possible solution for the duplicate `SELECT` i have above..

```
DECLARE @TempIDs TABLE
(
   ID int
);

INSERT INTO 
    @TempIDs 
--this is the select i have twice in the procedure above
SELECT 
    ID
FROM 
    TableA


SELECT COUNT(*) from @TempIDs
SELECT * FROM @TempIDs
```

In this case I the `SELECT` only once, but followed by two other `SELECTS` later, once using `*` and once `COUNT(*)`.

Is there no way to use `@TempIDs` like this? (*pseudo-code*):

```
IF COUNT_ROWS(@TempIDs) > 5
BEGIN
    UPDATE TableB SET value = "wow" WHERE ID IN (@TempIDs)
END
```

Comment: I'm unable to understand your requirements. Please add table scripts, sample data and expected output to your question. See this article for guidance: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/

Comment: As the tables/procedure may reveal private information I tried to avoid this, but I completely understand you. I will now copy and rename all the used tables and the procedure. Give me a few minutes. thank you for helping.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to put a query result in a table variable and iterate through the rows that can be easily done. Be careful with your loops of course.

```
DECLARE @Value int, @Label varchar(25)  
DECLARE @Tmp table (value int, label varchar(25)) 

INSERT INTO @Tmp (value, label) 
    SELECT 1, 'One' 
UNION SELECT 2, 'Two' 
UNION SELECT 3, 'Three' 

WHILE (SELECT count(1) FROM @Tmp) > 0 
BEGIN 
    SELECT TOP 1 @Value = value, @Label = label FROM @Tmp ORDER BY value 
    DELETE FROM @Tmp WHERE value = @Value 
    SELECT @Value 'value', @Label 'label' 
END
```

Comment: I feel like you answered my question, but my SQL-foo isn't good enough yet, to create this on my own. Would you kindly show me how this is done with `SELECT ID FROM TableA` assigned to a `tmp_var`. Later use this `tmp_var` to compare the `COUNT(ID)` of `tmp_var` with an integer and then in `WHERE otherID IN tmp_var`? thank you so much.